# Sublime Text 3 и Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sublime-text, процесс, sublime-text-3

В ST3 можно запускать Python скрипты (у меня по `F7`, по дефолту можно `Ctrl+B` или `Tools->Build`), вывод будет в консоль ST3 (т.е. окна консоли CMD нет), останавливать зависшие скрипты можно по `Tools->Cancel Build`.

Проблема в том, что если зависший скрипт не остановить, а запустить опять (по какой либо причине (например, после изменений)), то процесс с зависшим скриптом так и останется висеть, и убить его можно только через Диспетчер Задач (это ещё надо найти какой из `python.exe` тот самый зависший `python.exe`!).

Вопрос: как можно сделать, чтобы при повторном запуске скрипта, сначала **останавливался** уже запущенный, а потом запускался новый?  Как сделано, например, в PyCharm.

Comment: У Sublime Text есть многофункциональная IDE для Python — [**Anaconda**](http://damnwidget.github.io/anaconda/). Не мучьтесь, и используйте [**её Bulid System**](http://damnwidget.github.io/anaconda/IDE/#anaconda-s-build-system) или [**SublimeREPL**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23722631/5951529). Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных установил Anaconda, всякие подсказки работают.  Но проблема с тем, что процесс не останавливается при новом запуске скрипта осталась.